# How should I store a list in a database

Tags: database-design

How should I save a list of int(s) in a web app ?

I am designing a facebook-like app and for every user I need to save the ids of his friends, so a csv in the DB I don't think is indicated taking into account that a user cam even have 1000 friends and the database field that should contain this list is fixed, the csv may overflow that field.

Should I store these lists in local server files or is the database still the best option?

Comment: Careful with that list! Those are not ints you're handling! Those are *friends*! Do you really want to save a list of ints? Or a list of *friends* ?

Comment: every friend has an id that is an int (for now. i will encode it to a string later in the developing of the app )

Comment: I was trying (clearly I failed) to show that if you think about it as what it really is, a list of *friends*, the solution is obvious. A user has a list of (i.e. many) users as friends, and can be friends with many users. So, a many-to-many relationship is the answer.

Comment: Sorry for not getting the point at first. Thanks for the explanation !

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes came across this question today. Can't believe what a noob i was! thanks for the patience!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Many-to-many relationships are typically handled using a separate table.

```
user  |  friend
---------------
1     |  2
1     |  3
2     |  3
etc
```

You then use a JOIN to find out who is friends with a given user

Answer (score 6):

What you are looking for is a join table, joining Users to itself.  An entry in this table would represent a friendship between one user and another.

Users table

```
UserID | UserName | FirstName | LastName ...
```

Friends table

```
ID | UserID | FriendID
```

Both UserID and FriendID would be foreign keys to the Users table.  You'd probably want to have a uniqueness constraint on the pair (UserID,FriendID) and a non-unique index on UserID.  Note that UserID is the PK for the Users table and ID is the PK for the Friends table.  Using a separate PK for the Friends table will make it easier to refer to a particular user/user pair in your interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't store a list in a single field of the database - you will not be able to easily query it. Multi-valued columns are almost always the wrong choice.

In terms of database design, you should have a many-to-many table to connect users to friends (you may want to also store the corresponding opposite relationship in your table, for easy traversal of the bi-directional relationship).

Answer (score 1):

Use a database.

Today you might have 1000 friends.

Tomorrow, 10000. Obviously, this won't scale very well using only CSV.